# A second order ODE involving Jacobi elliptic functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

I have recently got stuck on this ODE in my studies of rogue waves on elliptic backgrounds:

$$
y'' + q(x) y' + w(x) y = 0
$$
where
$$
q(x) = m \frac{sn(x|m)\,cn(x|m)}{dn(x|m)}, \\
w(x) = \left(\lambda^2 + dn(x|m)^2 - i m \lambda \frac{sn(x|m)\,cn(x|m)}{dn(x|m)} \right)
$$
The parameter $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $m \in [0,1]$ is the elliptic parameter of the Jacobi elliptic functions $\text{dn}(.|.), \, \text{cn}(.|.)$ and $\text{sn}(.|.)$. I am only interested in $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Note that (according to Mathematica), the period of $q(x)$ is $4K(m)$ where $K$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. The real and imaginary parts of $w(x)$ have the same period as $q(x)$.

The initial value problem:
$$
y(0) = 2i\sin(\alpha),\\
y'(0) = 2(\lambda i \sin(\alpha) + i \cos(\beta))
$$
where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ are some parameters that depend on $\lambda$ in some complicated way.

Are there any specific tricks to help me find an analytical solution for this ODE? Does anyone have any pointers? I have checked a few handbooks on Jacobi elliptic functions but haven't had much luck, I have no formal training in elliptic functions and not too much in ODEs.

I have solved it numerically but I'm wondering if it's possible to solve it analytically for completeness.

EDIT: I have taken a look at [this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eglabahn/Papers/elliptic_odes.pdf) but it's a little too complicated for me. However, based on the transformation they present in equation 15:

$$
y(x) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int q(x)  dx\right)
$$
we can reduce the first equation to:
$$
u''(x) - r(x) u(x) = 0
$$
where
$$
r(x) = \frac{1}{2} q'(x) + \frac{1}{4} q^2(x) - w(x)
$$
According to Mathematica:
$$
r(x) = \frac{3 (m-1)+\text{dn}(x|m) \left(-\text{dn}(x|m) \left(3 \text{dn}(x|m)^2+4 \lambda ^2+m-2\right)+4 i m \text{cn}(x|m) \text{sn}(x|m)\right)}{4 \text{dn}(x|m)^2}
$$

I have expanded this in a Laurent series as suggested in the comments, but I am not sure how to properly manipulate the product of the series of $r(x) u(x)$ on the RHS of $u'' = r(x) u$.

Comment: Is the solution you are seeking elliptic (meromorphic doubly periodic) ? If so it suffices to locate its poles (more or less immediate from the localization of the poles of the coefficients of the ODE). You papers says there may be also more complicated solutions (involving exponential of elliptic functions).

Comment: @reuns I believe I am looking for are elliptic, yes. I know how to locate the poles but I'm not quite sure how to proceed after that. Could you point me towards a reference? Thank you!

Comment: You mean the poles of the coefficients ? For meromorphic/analytic functions the $l$-th derivative of $O( (z-a)^k)$ is $O( (z-a)^{k-l})$, so for each $a$ we can find the first few coefficients of the Laurent expansion of $y$ just from the first few coefficients of the Laurent expansion of the coefficients, ie. find the finitely many poles of $y$, with the Laurent expansion it determinates an elliptic function uniquely, constructed the same way as [$\wp(z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions)

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the explanation, I understand what you mean now. I am interested in the domain $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so I am not sure how to apply this method in this case since $w(x)$ and $q(x)$ (or $r(x)$) have no poles on that domain